# email format not coming in sharing

Tags: javascript, html, angular, email, templates

I need to share some data using email in share link and data need to paste directly in email subjest and heading data is dynamic in angular ts file ,

this.emailText = `mailto:?subject= Ignite Your Passion for Learning! Join Us at ${this.event?.title}&body=Get ready to embark on a journey of knowledge, inspiration, and growth like never before! We are thrilled to extend a special invitation to you for our upcoming ${this.event?.title}.

```
Whether you're seeking to enhance your expertise, explore new passions, or simply enrich your academic journey, ${this.event?.title} has something extraordinary to offer you.\n
Date: ${this.event?.start_date}\n 
Venue: ${this.event?.is_online?this.event?.online_event_details?.platform:this.event?.venue_name}\n\n

Mark your calendar and get ready to experience a dynamic blend of knowledge, networking, and excitement. Don't miss out on this golden opportunity to redefine your photography journey.\n

We can't wait to welcome you to ${this.event?.title} and witness your brilliance shine!\n

Joint at ${this.eventlUrl}/${this.event?.id}\n\n

Best regards,\n
${this.event?.institute}\n
[Your Title]
[Contact Information]`;
```

but \n is not working properly i tried \n 
 tag and '' also but not working i am using angualr

i am expecting data in fromat with line break in gmail body with complete formatting .

Comment: `<br>` instead of `\n`

Answer (score -1):

**I would suggest you try the html tag `<br>` or `%0D%0A`**

after modifying your code may look like this:

```
Whether you're seeking to enhance your expertise, explore new passions, or simply enrich your academic journey, ${this.event?.title} has something extraordinary to offer you.%0D%0A
Date: ${this.event?.start_date}%0D%0A
Venue: ${this.event?.is_online?this.event?.online_event_details?.platform:this.event?.venue_name}%0D%0A%0D%0A

Mark your calendar and get ready to experience a dynamic blend of knowledge, networking, and excitement. Don't miss out on this golden opportunity to redefine your photography journey.%0D%0A

We can't wait to welcome you to ${this.event?.title} and witness your brilliance shine!%0D%0A

Joint at ${this.eventlUrl}/${this.event?.id}%0D%0A%0D%0A

Best regards,%0D%0A
${this.event?.institute}%0D%0A
[Your Title]
[Contact Information]`;
```